pie chart type in pieConfig returns error unknown component
I'm using ant design and i'm implementing a pie chart using the the <Pie{...pieConfig}/>
and my configuration is as set below. When I add the type as outer and it returns an error saying unknown component: shape.outer, when I clear the type, the various divisions if the pie return undefined. Any assistance please.
const pieConfig = {
    appendPadding: 10,
    data: pieData,
    angleField: 'value',
    colorField: 'type',
    radius: 1,
    label: {
        type:"inner",
        content: '{name} {percentage}', // Shows name and percentage
        style: {
            fontSize: 12,
        },
    },
    interactions: [{ type: 'element-active' }],
    legend: {
        position: 'bottom',
    },
};```

